# Config log4j2 with JSON

Tags: json, log4j2

I have below simple config for log4j2 which just log the message to console stdout and a file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <RandomAccessFile name="FILE" fileName="app.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </RandomAccessFile>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

It working fine, but if I change to JSON config, if doesn't work, if anybody have any clue?

```
{ "configuration": 
{ 
    "appenders": {
        "RandomAccessFile": { "name": "FILE", "fileName": "app.log",
            "PatternLayout": { "pattern": "%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" }
        },
        "Console": { "name": "STDOUT", 
            "PatternLayout": { "pattern": "%m%n" }
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "root": { "level": "trace", 
            "AppenderRef": { "ref": "STDOUT" }, 
            "AppenderRef": { "ref": "FILE" }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The log4j2 JSON (or any JSON for that matter) doesn't allow two "AppenderRef" entries to exist, so you should use a config more like the following

```
{ "configuration":
{
    "appenders": {
        "RandomAccessFile": { "name": "FILE", "fileName": "app.log",
            "PatternLayout": { "pattern": "%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" }
        },
        "Console": { "name": "STDOUT",
            "PatternLayout": { "pattern": "%m%n" }
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "root": { "level": "trace",
            "AppenderRef": [
                { "ref": "STDOUT" },
                { "ref": "FILE" }
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```

You can also use 'appender-ref' instead of AppenderRef

Answer (score 0):

You may have found a bug. Could you file a Jira ticket in the log4j2 issue tracker?